# Scrapy - Grabbing Multiple Items

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

Very new to scrapy, so bear with me.

First, here is my code:

```
from scrapy.spider     import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector     import HtmlXPathSelector
from usdirectory.items    import UsdirectoryItem
from scrapy.http    import Request


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name         = "usdirectory"
    allowed_domains    = ["domain.com"]
    start_urls    = ["url_removed_sorry"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs     = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles     = hxs.select('//*[@id="holder_result2"]/a[1]/span/span[1]/text()').extract()
        for title in titles:
                item = UsdirectoryItem()
                item["title"] = title
                item


        yield item
```

That works...but it only grabs the first item.

I noticed in the items I am trying to scrape, the Xpath changes for each row. For example, the first row is the xpath you see above:

```
//*[@id="holder_result2"]/a[1]/span/span[1]/text()
```

then it increments by 2, all the way to 29. So the second result:

```
//*[@id="holder_result2"]/a[3]/span/span[1]/text()
```

Last result:

```
//*[@id="holder_result2"]/a[29]/span/span[1]/text()
```

So my question is how do I get the script to grab all those, and I don't care if i have to copy and paste code for every item. All the other pages are exactly the same. I'm just not sure how to go about it.

Thank you very much.

Edit:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class UsdirectoryItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
```

Comment: It may be a code formatting issue in your question, but one problem is that "yield item" needs to be inside the "for title" loop. With one yield only at the end of "parse", you'll get only 1 item back

Answer (score 1):

Given the pattern is exactly as you described, you can use XPath [modulo operator](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#numbers) `mod` on position index of `a` to get all the target `a` elements :

```
//*[@id="holder_result2"]/a[position() mod 2 = 1]/span/span[1]/text()
```

For a quick demo, consider the following input XML :

```
<div>
 <a>1</a>
 <a>2</a>
 <a>3</a>
 <a>4</a>
 <a>5</a>
</div>
```

Given this XPath `/div/a[position() mod 2 = 1]`, the following elements will be returned :

```
<a>1</a>
<a>3</a>
<a>5</a>
```

See live demo in xpathtester.com [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/b219522bb3cafc152b7c2b3289e642f4)

Comment: ok when i put in that xpath, it only grabs the last record, not anything in between. thoughts?

Comment: @dkeeper09 The problem is almost certainly that you do not show your input document.

Comment: Ok check the original post, see if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @dkeeper09 Not really I'm afraid. By input document I meant an HTML source document we can use to reproduce your problem. If it's too large, then show a significant, relevant portion of it.

Comment: Oh you mean the source of the page I'm trying to scrape?

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works for you. Notice we are iterating over a[i] instead of a[1]. The results are stored in a list (hopefully).

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    for i in xrange(15):
        titles = hxs.select('//*[@id="holder_result2"]/a[' + str(1+i*2) + ']/span/span[1]/text()').extract()
        for title in titles:
                item = UsdirectoryItem()
                item["title"] = title
                item #erroneous line?
        items.append(item)
        yield item
```

Comment: i got a boatload of errors with this one, but I'm going to play around with the code and see if I can make it work.

Comment: Please do not submit answers with untested code, it is useless if you are not sure what your code does. `for i in xrange(15)` does _not_ return `1,3,5...` and `i` is not interpolated inside the XPath string.

Comment: Thanks @Mathias-Müller. Didn't copy over part of my code. In my sleep deprived state, I also somehow expected 'i' to be interpolated. dkeeper09: Did you get things working?

Comment: No this didn't work :/ It didn't give me any results.

Comment: Thanks. I'll generate some dummy pages to test with. Might take me a day or two to get to it.